# How do I make ActiveRecord::Schema.define not log to stdout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I can't see this in the docs, but I presume it's a solved problem.

I'm using ActiveRecord outside Rails, and my script loads a schema.rb dumped from another app.  I want to load this schema without dumping the migration output to stdout, but replacing ActiveRecord::Base.logger doesn't shut it up.  What should I be overriding to stop the noise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is apparently in ActiveRecord::Migration:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = false
```

This makes migrations not output information to $stdout.  There is a convenience wrapper method called .suppress_messages, which you can use like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.suppress_messages do
  load("path/to/schema.rb")
end
```

And yes, this is documented under Migration (but not under Schema, where I was looking).

Comment: This answer saved my life after more than 10 years 

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = begin
  l = Logger.new('/dev/null')
  l.level = Logger::FATAL
  l
end
```

Comment: No. I have tried this. Replacing ActiveRecord::Base.logger doesn't shut it up.

Comment: I've posted the correct answer above.  The problem with your answer is that schema loading doesn't go through ActiveRecord::Base.logger at all.  It just uses a bare `puts`.

Comment: Oh. Interesting. I didn't know that. Thanks